# JSON Class with a List of another Class

Tags: c#, json, nsjsonserialization

I'll try to explain this as best as I can. I have a class called Prospect which contains strings of email, company, firstname, lastname, phone.

I have the requirement to ouput Prospect information in JSON in the format of

```
[
   {"email":"test@test.com",
      "properties":[
      {
        "property":"company",
        "value": "Company Name"
      },
        "property":"firstname",
        "value":"John"
      },
        "property":"surname",
         "value":"Smith"
      },
        "property":"phone",
        "value":"01234567891"
      }]
  }
]
```

I need to output JSON of all prospects I capture. I have tried this by creating a class of Customer:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public List<Property> properties { get; set; }

}
```

and a class of Property:

```
public class Property
{
    public string property { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

I cant for the life of me get the result i am after. I thinks its the List of Property in the Customer class. If i change the List to a string and define only one value here, the output is fine.

Please help :(

Comment: include the code that is used to deserialize the json. Also, json doesn't seem to be well formatted. there is no opening curly brace for 2nd, 3rd and 4th property.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to offer help. I am trying to communicate with HubSpot CRM. Their API docs show how the JSON should be formatted but I cant figure out how to do it. Page is here [link](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/contacts/batch_create_or_update)

Comment: JSONLint reports what you posted as invalid.  That link is blocked for me so I cant check anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

Thank you to everyone who provided comments. Your guidance helped me resolve my issue.

```
        public class Customer
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
        public List<Property> properties { get; set; }
    }

    public class Property
    {
        public string property { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Customer _c = new Customer();
        _c.email = email.Text;
        _c.properties = new List<Property>();
        _c.properties.Add(new Property{ property = "company", value = company.Text });
        _c.properties.Add(new Property { property = "website", value = website.Text });
        _c.properties.Add(new Property { property = "firstname", value = firstname.Text });
        _c.properties.Add(new Property { property = "lastname", value = lastname.Text });
        _c.properties.Add(new Property { property = "phone", value = phone.Text });

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_c, Formatting.Indented);
        outputBox.Text = json;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
public class Property
    {
      public string property { get; set; }
      public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
      public string email { get; set; }
      public List<Property> properties { get; set; }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string JSON = @"[
   {""email"":""test @test.com"",
      ""properties"":[
      {
        ""property"":""company"",
        ""value"": ""Company Name""
      },
       { ""property"":""firstname"",
        ""value"":""John""
      },
       { ""property"":""surname"",
         ""value"":""Smith""
      },
       { ""property"":""phone"",
        ""value"":""01234567891""
      }]
  }
]
";
      Customer[] obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer[]>(JSON);

    }
```

Please note:
1. I have to add missing opening `{` brackets to properties' elements.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help @Max I cant get it to work at all. How do i get that to output to the console or to a string? I think my lack of knowledge and experience are the biggest contributors to my inability. Thanks again

Comment: @Swanne, there is no otput. To test how it works, just set a break point after the deserialization (at the last `}`) and then use Shift+F9 to view `obj` properties (when breaks, hover the cursor over the `obj` variable to see its properties in a floating windows, or put the typing cursor on it and press Shift+F9).